# Dataframe from console gives me an error when knitting in rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am trying to knitr with rmarkdown using data from the global environment into rmarkdown for publishing.
The two data frames are `survival.dataset` and `survival.data.subset`
I have called my rmd for output2
In my normal script I have added this code in the end.

```
df <- data.frame()
df.sub <- data.frame()

my_env <- new.env()
my_env$df <- survival.dataset
my_env$df.sub <- survival.data.subset


rmarkdown::render('output2.Rmd', envir = my_env)
```

And then I move to the rmarkdown output2 where I try to run something like:

````
```{r}
broom::tidy(
  coxph(Surv(censor.time_new, status) ~ proned,
        data = survival.dataset), 
  exp = TRUE) 
```
````

This works fine and the output is produced correct so rmarkdown is able to run statistics based on the data from the console, but when I try to knitr into a word document I get this error:

[image: Error when using knitr button]

So it looks like `survival.dataset` is still somehow missing when using knitting?